# Powershell script for Account Expiration date outputs wrong format

Tags: powershell

We have a script which emails managers when an AD account is within 14 days of expiring, but the displayed date format is in mmddyyy and for the life of me i can't get it to display ddmmyyy

```
$From = "xxxx"
$CC = "xxxx", "xxxx"
#$BCC = "xxxx"
$SMTPServer = "xxxx"
$startDate = Get-Date
$endDate = $startDate.AddDays(14)
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter {AccountExpirationDate -gt $startDate -and AccountExpirationDate -lt $endDate} -Properties AccountExpirationDate, Manager
Foreach($User in $Users)
{
$Manager = Get-ADUser $User.Manager -Properties EmailAddress
#Set our dynamic variables
$To = $Manager.EmailAddress
$Subject = "Account Expiration Notification for " + $User.Name
$Body = 
"Hi $($Manager.Name),
This notification is to inform you that the account for $($User.Name) will expire on $($User.AccountExpirationDate) 
From this date the account will not be able to access any ICT services and will be deleted one month following expiry.
If you need to extend the account for this member of your team, please raise a Service Desk ticket via xxxx giving details of the extension needed and new date of expiry.
It is important to take action now to avoid any unnecessary disruption for your team member.
Thank you,
ICT Help Desk"
Send-MailMessage -To xxxx -cc xxxx -From $From -Subject $Subject -SmtpServer xxxx -Body $Body
}
```

Comment: Change `$($User.AccountExpirationDate)` to `$('{0:ddMMyyy}' -f $User.AccountExpirationDate)`

Comment: That totally worked, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You can format any `[datetime]` value however you like, by either passing an appropriate format string to the `ToString()` method on the object, or by using the `-f` string format operator (which will then do the same for you):

```
$body = " ... $('{0:ddMMyyy}' -f $User.AccountExpirationDate) ... "
```